# Global Action not showing up on User Profile Page

Tags: global-actions

I created a Global Action that shows a VF page, and when I used the Global Publisher to add that action to the list, it works in most places (Chatter, almost all object types). The one place it doesn't seem to work is on the User record. I can edit the Page Layout to remove standard Actions, but custom Actions seem to get ignored regardless of whether you inherit from the Global Publisher or customize the User Page Layout's Action section. Has anyone else seen this or figured out a way around it?

Comment: I got a comment from support saying it wasn't supported after they looked into it. Seems strange since the option is definitely available in the User's page layout...

Comment: Yes thats weird...We're able to add that action in User Pagelayout...But for User there won't be any chatter feed!! so it won't work i guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not personally tried this, but I know the User object isn't "normal". For instance, it doesn't support workflows, or inline editing on the page layout, and has locked areas on the page that can't be moved around. My suspicion is that this truly is not implemented yet, but have nothing to confirm that.

Comment: It would make sense, just kind of interesting the UI to set it up is there on the backend (and of course all of these Chatter Actions look the same across the object types, so I make my own assumptions) :D